# Yaws - socket_closed_remotely

Tags: concurrency, erlang, yaws

Hello fellow Erlangers :)

Just another Erlang enthusiast playing with the language here. I have a very simple YAWS app module which works fine when accessed by single clients. However, when I try to spawn multiple concurrent clients, some of those clients start receiving errors (even if the number of those clients is very low, say 10). Any idea what can be causing it?

Illustrating code:

**App Module**

```
out(Arg) ->
  io:format("got something!\n"),
  Method = extract_method(Arg),
  handle(Method, Arg).
```

**Client**

```
client(SenderPID) ->
case httpc:request(
  put,
  {
    "http://localhost:8080/storageunit",
    [],
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    ""
  }, [], []) of
    { error, Reason } -> io:format("Server responded with an error: ~p.\n", [Reason]);
    { ok, _ } -> ok
  end,
  SenderPID ! 'FINISHED'.

client_spawner(_SenderPID, 0) -> io:format("Done.\n");
client_spawner(SenderPID, Times) ->
  spawn(concurrent, client, [SenderPID]),
  client_spawner(SenderPID, Times - 1).
```

The errors I'm getting:

> Server responded with an error: socket_closed_remotely.

The last piece of info is:

- 10 concurrent clients - from 2 to 5 errors on average
- 100-100000 concurrent clients - 50% errors on average

I thought my handling code causes it, but in scenarios where the clients receive httpc errors, the server doesn't even react with a "got something!".

I'm sure I'm missing something trivial, can you help?

Regards,
Piotr

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more details of what `handle/2` is doing on the server side. I recommend checking Yaws logs to see if there's any relevant there. Also, make sure your Yaws listen backlog is set high enough for what you're trying, and make sure maximum numbers of file descriptors for both client and server are set appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. See, the problem is handle/2 does not even get called. I read somewhere on github (some old issue in some repo) that it could be caused by the profile used by inets. I plan to explore that a bit.

Comment: Yes, just confirmed. Even when I completely rule the handle/2 out of the equation, I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Is Yaws receiving anything at all, or this is just a client-side issue?

Comment: It looks like a client-side issue. Yaws isn't getting anything at all.

Comment: Well, only when the client receives that error.

Comment: OK, I have an interesting update: running the same client code against google.com yields expected results (i.e. all spawned clients run the httpc request successfully). Gist: https://gist.github.com/PiotrJustyna/2cca8798afbf9be644e1a8546a423d63 It gets really interesting. I think I will check it against my vanilla yaws locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must have been something wrong with my initial code. I rewrote the module from scratch and it is giving me expected results. Here's the code:

```
-module(annoying_client).
-export([annoy/0, client/1, client_spawner/2]).

client(SenderPID) ->
  case httpc:request("http://www.google.com") of
    { error, Reason } -> io:format("Error. Reason: ~p\n", [Reason]);
    { ok, _ } -> io:format("ok\n")
  end,
  SenderPID ! 'FINISHED'.

client_spawner(_SenderPID, 0) -> io:format("Done.\n");
client_spawner(SenderPID, Times) ->
  spawn(?MODULE, client, [SenderPID]),
  client_spawner(SenderPID, Times - 1).

annoy() ->
  inets:start(),

  spawn(?MODULE, client_spawner, [self(), 100]),
  wait_for_all_jobs(1),

  inets:stop(),
  init:stop().

wait_for_all_jobs(NumberOfFinishedJobs) ->
  receive 'FINISHED' ->
    if
      NumberOfFinishedJobs < 100 ->
        wait_for_all_jobs(NumberOfFinishedJobs + 1);
      true ->
        io:format("All jobs finished.\n")
    end
  end.
```

It works like a charm with both:

- google
- local vanilla yaws

GETs and PUTs. The problems start when I cross the threshold of 2000 concurrent requests but I'm guessing it is to be expected judging by the numbers obtained locally and remotely. In case of 2000 requests, I'm getting roughly:

- 6 errors while requesting google.com
- 500 errors while requesting local yaws

The errors I'm getting:

```
Error. Reason: socket_closed_remotely
```

and

```
Error. Reason: {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"www.google.com",80}}, {inet,[inet],system_limit}]}
```

DoS protection? Incorrect configuration? Anyway, I am happy enough with my current results. Probably will experiment with other Erlang web servers just to get some performance numbers.

Thank you all.